# how to get the the IP address that is accessing MongoDB database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, azure-web-app-service

i need to secure the database to only access request from app server ( backend node.js and express.js)

when whitelisting the ip address of app server(azure app service linux), it breaks and can not connect.
i tried to whitelist the web server(frontend react azure app service windows) as well and its not working.
when whitelist 0.0.0.0 it works, so the question is what ip is making the request if it is not the app or the web is it the user?
and how to obtain that information?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that your firewall blocks all outside IPs except for the IP of your app server and allow access to your database server on port `27017`.

Edit your `/etc/mongod.conf` file.

Ensure these lines appear below `# network interfaces`

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

You can test your setup by downloading a MongoDB desktop client like `Robo 3T` and whitelisting your own home/office computer's IP address for your server's firewall on port `27017`.

To access your log file to see which IPs are accessing your database, look again at your `/etc/mongod.conf` file and look for `# where to write logging data`. This will be something like `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

You can dump your log file to the terminal with this command:

```bash
sudo cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```